# Typescript: Chakra UI Box component not accepting 'align' as prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

Having some difficulty diagnosing this issue. Still learning Typescript so apologies if missing something obvious.

Trying to create a footer component using Chakra UI, and run into an odd type error using 'align' prop.

TS error 2322 suggests that 'align' is not a valid type for the Box component, and checking the [chakra docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/box/usage) they suggest using 'alignItems' for Box.

Which would make sense, except, 'alignItems' doesn't work, and 'align' does...when I run this in vanilla javascript align works as expected, and alignItems has no effect.

```
import {Box} from '@chakra-ui/react';

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <Box mt={5} position={'static'} as="footer" w="100%">
      <Box className="copyright" align="left">
        Copyright 2022
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

And the error code on compile:

```
ERROR in src/components/Footer.tsx:6:34
TS2322: Type '{ children: string; className: string; align: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & OmitCommonProps<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, keyof ChakraProps> & ChakraProps & { ...; }'.
  Property 'align' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & OmitCommonProps<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, keyof ChakraProps> & ChakraProps & { ...; }'.
```

Comment: Which version of Chakra UI are you using ?

Comment: Latest as far as I know `@chakra-ui/react": "^2.3.5"`

Comment: Indeed, I am able to reproduce it even on v2.2.6